# I'm trying to define a function for the decimate modifier without success

Tags: python, modifiers

I'm writing a plugin for Blender to apply the decimate modifier automatically given an angle limit. I'm working on this little project just for fun and also to meet some of my recent needs.

I'm trying to define a function with an argument that goes as follows:

```
deg5 = radians(5)
deg30 = radians(30)
deg45 = radians(45)
deg60 = radians(60)
deg90 = radians(90)   

def apply_decimate_modifier(degrees):
        
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DECIMATE')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].decimate_type = 'DISSOLVE'
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].angle_limit = {degrees}
        #bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Decimate", report=True)
```

then I'm trying to put this function on the Operator:

```
#defines class for the Angle Limit of 5 degrees.
class decimate_5degrees(bpy.types.Operator):
    """
    Set Planar Mode Angle Limit to 5°
    """

    bl_idname = "decimate.5degrees"
    bl_label = "Angle Limit: 5°"
    
    #TODO:
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None
    
    def execute(self, context):
        apply_decimate_modifier(deg5)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

However, Blender gives me the following error message:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 67, in execute
  File "\Text", line 49, in apply_decimate_modifier
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: DecimateModifier.angle_limit expected a float type, not set
```

I don't understand why is this happening because the "deg5 (...) deg90" variables are already float numbers. Am I missing something?

Also, I don't know if the following piece of code is sufficient for Blender to only apply the modifier if a mesh object is selected. How could I translate it to Blender so the Decimate Modifier is applied ONLY to an object if it's selected, and if nothing is selected, Blender shouldn't apply any modifiers to any random objects.

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return context.active_object is not None
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The braces are not necessary here;

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].angle_limit = {degrees}
```

Instead assign angle_limit like so;

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].angle_limit = degrees
```

The error message is telling you that angle_limit has been assigned the incorrect type.

```
DecimateModifier.angle_limit expected a float type, not set
```

Perhaps the wording of the error is confusing. After all the word 'set' holds the record for being the word with the most definitions. Anyway, just remove the braces and you're all set!

As for the second part of your question;

You could add to the conditional in your poll method as follows;

```
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None and context.active_object.select_get() is True and context.active_object.type == 'MESH'
```

Comment: Oops! It works! Thank you so much! I was getting very confused because I didn't know exactly how to declare arguments to a function in Python, because I'm still used to C.

Also, do you know how I could solve the 2nd part of my problem?

Comment: Edited to add a suggestion for how to ensure active object is selected to the poll method.

Comment: I tried doing this but so far what I got was this error message when I select the right option:

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\ui_pie_menu.py", line 68, in execute
  File "\ui_pie_menu.py", line 48, in apply_decimate_modifier
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\BlenderFoundation.Blender_3.4.1.0_x64__ppwjx1n5r4v9t\Blender\3.4\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 113, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties:  enum "DECIMATE" not found in ()

Comment: Updated the poll() method test to include testing that the selected object type is MESH. This should address the error.

Comment: Hello, and thanks a lot! This worked like a charm. I have only one more question about this: When I run the script now and select to decimate an object that's not a mesh, Blender displays an error message. Is it possible to choose not to display it? I don't know if an error message would be a good thing for the end user, rather than Blender just ignoring an element that's not a Mesh for example.

Comment: What's wrong with reporting an error? If a user performs an action and nothing happens without any report the system would appear to be unresponsive. The user should expect a successful execution of the operation, or a message indicating that an invalid action was performed.

Comment: I guess you're right! In any way, is there a way of making the pie menu available only on object mode? I don't know what's better: Locking the shortcut to object mode only or adding an argument to the poll() method.

Comment: I would suggest opening another question about the pie menu aspect of your add-on. I suspect the `draw()` method of the pie menu could inspect the context and determine which menu items to include/exclude.